# HTTP status 404 in eclipse Spring MVC 4 +Hibernate with MySQL + Tiles.xml

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, web.xml

I already searching about my error but I got nothing. still error in my code so i have to post my question here.
I got an error when I run my project in eclipse with tomcat server.
I already finish the project in Spring MVC 4 + Hibernate with MongoDB. now I have to switch into Hibernate with MySQL, I am starting the project in eclipse. but when I complete the configuration of spring with hibernate its shows error.
error and structure of project are following below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2I3a.png)

web.xml

```
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>ApplicationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DMS_MySQL</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DMS_MySQL</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/assets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pages/error/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

SpringMVC-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" //urls//">
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesviewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    <property name="order" value="2"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="jstlviewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="3"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enable autowire -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cs" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dms" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cs.bean" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">test</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <import resource="/WEB-INF/SpringMVC-servlet.xml"/> 
</beans>
```

LoginController.java

package com.cs.controller;

```
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public String execute(HttpSession session, Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("user", new UserBean());
        UserBean tempUser = (UserBean) session.getAttribute("USER");        
        if (tempUser != null) {
            return "redirect:/home";
        }
        return "logn";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/performLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginProcess(HttpSession session, Model model, @ModelAttribute("user") UserBean user,
            BindingResult result) throws Exception
    {
        UserBean tempUser = (UserBean) session.getAttribute("USER");
        if(tempUser != null)
        {           
            return "redirect:/home";
        }
        if(user == null)
        {           
            model.addAttribute("user", new UserBean());
            return "login";
        }
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(user.getName()))
        {
            result.rejectValue("name", "error.required.username");
        }
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(user.getPassword()))
        {
            result.rejectValue("password", "error.required.password");
        }
        if(!result.hasErrors())
        {
            tempUser = userService.findByCredential(user);
            if(tempUser != null)
            {               
                if (tempUser.getRole().equals(RoleEnum.ADMIN)) {                    
                    session.setAttribute("USER", tempUser);
                    return "redirect:/home";
                } else if (tempUser.getRole().equals(RoleEnum.CASHIER)) {                   
                    session.setAttribute("USER", tempUser);
                    return "redirect:/cHome";
                }               
            }           
            else
            {
                result.reject("error.valid.usernamePassword");
            }
        }       
        user.setMobile("");
        model.addAttribute("user", user);       
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:8080/DMS_MySQL/login. 
Also try changing your login controller as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String execute(HttpSession session, Model model) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("user", new UserBean());
    UserBean tempUser = (UserBean) session.getAttribute("USER");        
    if (tempUser != null) {
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
    return "login";//typo in your code
}
```

I assume you have defined mapping for login in tiles configuration.

Answer (score 0):

here i find this sentence

```
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
```

and where is your applicationContext.xml

Comment: wait I will add it.